# How to set environment variable for MCR in Ubuntu

Tags: matlab

I am new to ubuntu. I am using matlab in ubuntu. I used 'mcc' command in matlab(ubuntu) to create executable files.

Now to run those executables I need to set the 'MCR' directory path to the environment variable. I used 'setenv' but, it says 'setenv is not found. the following is what I did-

```
setenv PATH/<mcr root path>/v7.17: "$PATH"
```

And I get the following output-

```
No command 'setenv' found, did you mean command 'neten'
from package 'netenv'
setenv: commmand not found
```

Can you please help me telling how do I set the environment variable in ubuntu to run my executable files.

Comment: Cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731671/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-ubuntu

Comment: yes I asked in stackoverflow fast, but somebody suggested to ask me here.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that setenv is a *csh (e.g. tcsh) built in for setting environmental variables. There are different "shells" -- that is, programs which provide you with a command line, and they have different syntax. Most Linux distributions come with a pre-installed shell called `bash`, in which setting environmental variables requires a different syntax.

In bash, try

```
export PATH=$PATH:/what/ever/path/v7.17
```

(export is usually unnecessary unless the PATH variable has not been set yet, which normally is not the case)

Alternatively, install tcsh (`sudo apt-get install tcsh`), start tcsh from the command line and enter your original command.

Update: the next error in line is that a shared library is missing. Probably you need to set up an environmental variable, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, to point to where this library is. Find the directory where matlab keeps its shared libraries, and do

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/the/matlab/lib/directory/
```

Also, please take a look at this question (first hit when you google for "shared library libmwi18n.so is not found"): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972819/mcr-libmwi18n-so-file-missing

Comment: Hi I set the variable using the run_application.shell<mcr directory>, but now my machine is complaining about 'libmwi18n.so'.   It says 'shared library libmwi18n.so is not found'

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer, even after doing it having the same error, I have asked a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737143/shared-lib-libmwi18n-so-not-find please help me out.